# Image Upload PHP Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having some trouble uploading an image to the server. The image should be uploaded to the directory IteamImages and the name should be in the format: $userid_$date.png

Two Problems:

**The image doesnt seem to show up in the directory**

**The image name shows up as: upload/Array_20140906072547.png (instead
    of upload/4_20140906072547.png)**

```
$UserId=$_POST['UserId']; 
$uploaddir = "IteamImages/";
$DateLastEdit = $UserID."_".date("YmdHis");
$dateCreates = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$file = $DateLastEdit.".png";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"].$file;
}
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"].$file,
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"].$file);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"].$file;
    }

mysql_query("UPDATE ItemDetails SET ItemImage='$file' WHERE UserID ='$UserID' AND Id='$last'");
```

This is part of the html form:

```
<form action="manual-item-post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
UserId: <input type="text" name="UserId"><br>
<label for="file">Image Upload:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_FILES["file"]` is an array and when you concatenate it `echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"].$file;` PHP automatically converts it to string, resulting in `Array`.

I suppose you wanted it to be `echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $file;`

Also you might want to change `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"].$file, "upload/" . $_FILES["file"].$file);` to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);` (`$_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']` is the path of the uploaded temp file you want to move)

And `$DateLastEdit = $UserID."_".date("YmdHis");` will always result in "_DATE" as the variable is wrong (needs to be `$DateLastEdit = (int)$UserId."_".date("YmdHis");`)

PS: I cast $UserId to integer, otherwise directory traversal is possible (e.g., post `../../something/` as UserId). And by directly passing user entered data to an SQL query, you also have a SQL injection.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer. i solved both issues.